# How best to melt and reform chocolate

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate

I'm planning on making a custom box of chocolates using a home-made silicone food/ice-cube tray.  I think I'll need to get the chocolate pretty hot and runny so that it will pick up the details in the tray with few air bubbles.  I expect this might take some experimentation but would like some idea where to start.

What is the best process to use to melt and reform the chocolate so that it keeps as many of its original properties as possible rather than turning crumbly or loosing its creamy taste?  Should I be melting slowly/quickly? should I add anything to the chocolate (milk, butter, etc.)? should I leave at room temperature to solidify or refrigerate immediately?

If it maters, I'll be using galaxy chocolate (and possibly milky way chocolate) which I think melts at a lower temperature than most?

Comment: I am not good with chocolate (except eating it), so I will leave the details to others, but the word you are looking for is "tempering" chocolate. And it's tricky to get right.

Comment: if not doing so already, warm the molds to the same temp as the goop before pouring and _slowly_ cool.

Comment: Are you starting with powder and adding fat & sugar &... or just melting solid bits to reform. What do you mean by 'Milky Way Chocolate' (are you planning on melting the whole bar, which is far more than just 'chocolate'?). Please (if possible) include a photo of the silicone molds you plan to use, the volume per piece might affect...

Comment: @CosCallis Definitely starting with solid bars and reforming.  By "Milky way chocolate" I mean MilkyWay Brand Chocolate e.g. Magic Stars.

Comment: Hi, I wonder if this is not a duplicate - please see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84011/how-to-solidify-melted-chocolate, are you trying to do the same or something else?

Comment: @rumtscho I don't think so?  That question doesn't seem to be about melting and reforming milk chocolate.  Some of the answers may have applicable information though.  I'll take a better look when I'm more awake.

Answer (score 2):

Chocolate IS tricky to get right, and I have had mixed results using a double boiler, I have also tried using a microwave- ten seconds intervals, checking temperature each time and waiting till the chocolate is good and warm before stirring. I have also used this method- place chocolate in a plastic bag and leave it in a warm sunbeam or outside if it is a warm day until melted, IF you have the patience for this method, I have consistently had good results with this method. In regards to your concerns about air bubbles, I would definetely use either room temperature molds or warm molds, gently banging the molds on your contertop after you add the chocolate will cause air bubbles to rise to the top. I would also suggest letting the chocolate cool to room temperature on your countertop before placing in the fridge to harden. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1  If nothing else it gives me somewhere to start.  Slow melt to a high enough temperature to get it runny, then a slow chill.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, and remember chocolate is super finicky(which I'm sure you already know), and a failure can always be rolled into balls coated in sprinkles, powdered sugar, rice crispies, toasted chopped nuts or cocoa powder and called truffles! Good luck